# Assigning Number Values to String Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to find a way to make an array with strings have values such as [1, 2, 3, 4,...] and so on.I believe I saw a way to do it utilizing 'indexOf + 1' thanks for any help.

```
function sortGrades(lst){
var grades = ["VB", "V0", "V0+","V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", 
"V8",` "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17"];

 }
```

Comment: What to do you mean by "make an array with strings have values such as [1, 2, 3, 4,...]". Like creating another array with numbers, add numbers to each string on the array, order the array based on the strings, or another thing? Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: "VB" would equal "1", "V0" would equal "2", etc. all the way to "V17." I'm trying to find an easier way to do this than to list 17 variables with number values.

Comment: @bgongre What would `VA` then be? Please give us the procedure on how do you map those strings to numbers

Comment: `array.map(function(d,i){return i + 1})`.

Comment: What is your use case? Objective is  confusing without a proper explanation. Please take some time to read through [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply using `map`:

```js
var grades = ["VB", "V0", "V0+","V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", 
"V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17"];
var numericGrades = grades.map((grade, index) => index + 1);

console.log(numericGrades);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
grades.map(function(v,i) { return i + 1; });
// Or cleaner but ES5:
grades.map((v,i) => i+1)
```

Even though I might have misunderstood your question.